# Degradable Ajax Jquery Pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a site which has pages of content. I would like the pagination to be AJAX driven via Jquery, so that when the user clicks to go to a new page, the content is updated without a page reload.

However, for users that do not have javascript enabled, including search bots, I would like the pagination to work without javascript being enabled.

Is this possible, and if so, how can it be done?I am coding the site in Python if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess a good approach to this would be to create the page without any Javascript at all. You would end up with something like this:

```
<div class="content">
    ...
</div>
<a class="prev" href="previousPage">Prev</a>
<a class="next" href="nextPage">Next</a>
```

As you can imagine the content goes in the `content` div and the `Next` and `Prev` links load different pages via simple HTML.

Then you can include some jQuery like this:

```
$('.next').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do the ajax call and load the resulting data in the content div
});
```

With this solution, if Javascript is not enabled the pagination would work correctly, as it is made with simple HTML. However, if Javascript is enabled the ajax call will do its magic.